# Change title of taskbar icon in windows xp

Tags: windows, windows-xp, taskbar

How do i change the name/title of taskbar icon in windows xp? for example, I got 3 firefoxes with similar websites opened (the same portal but different webpages) and I want to differentiate them. I want to set the windows of all taskbar icons according to my wish(titles) to any string.. Is there some utility? Google didn't really help.. :"(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wsTaskborg Taskbar Organizer. Using it, you can create your own groups and assign a title to each group. If u want, you can also create a 1-member group and assign any title of your choice.

http://download.cnet.com/wsTaskborg/3000-2072_4-10632012.html

http://w-shadow.com/wstaskborg/

Answer (score 1):

There's not really a general one for ALL programs, but you can customize the firefox titles with [this addon.](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/57/)

Comment: yeah, thx, but I use firefox at work for fun only... I need that thing for IE primarily.

Comment: By default IE displays the page title first.  You can edit the "Internet Explorer" portion by following directions http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176497  to edit the registry.

Comment: OK, whatever, but situation is still same, I need it to start with "A" or "B" or whatever I want :)