# is there a way to sort and rename open windows in Windows XP taskbar?

Tags: windows-xp, taskbar, rename, sorting

I want to rename and if possible sort my open Windows in the task bar.

The reason is that some programs I use (pgAdmin, Windows Explorer, Google Chrome) put names on the Windows from which I cannot differentiate what the content may be (e.g. Edit Data - *ServerName*[*ServerIP*] - *DataBase* - *TableName* when I'm only interested in table name and everything after *ServerName* is not visible).

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/168282/change-title-of-taskbar-icon-in-windows-xp for the renaming part of your question. I don't think you can sort without installing a 3rd party tool though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never come across anything to rename windows, but there are a few options for sorting them. I use [taskix](http://taskix.robustit.com/), does the job for me.